# Formula for identifying the 555 timer IC chip interval

Tags: integrated-circuit

Hi I am pursuing my hobby in electronics and I would like to learn more about IC chips. I have searched the internet for the most basic IC chip and the result is the 555 timer IC chip, I was wondering what is the formula for identifying the time interval of a 555 timer IC chip.

Comment: these formulas are readily available on the internet mr Miguel

Comment: What formula should I follow??
1st formula: time = resistance * capacitance
2nd formula: time = 1.1 * resistance * capacitance

Comment: Can you be little more specific in your question? As in which configuration you are using the 555 etc..

Comment: Read the manual. -1

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you want to do. If you want the 555 timer to output a periodic signal then you want it to operate as **astable**. If you want it to trigger only once after a given delay(which you will set) then that's **monostable.**

Like i said earlier, these are readily available. I just tried to clear out whichever you might need. These are the formulas for the corresponding operating modes of the 555 timer.

- [Astable](http://www.csgnetwork.com/ne555timer2calc.html)
- [Monostable](http://www.csgnetwork.com/ne555timer1calc.html)

Answer (score 1):

**Monostable ("One-Shot" - Turns on for a period, then turns off and stays off):**

Period (HIGH-time before switching LOW):

[image]

**Astable (Oscillator - Turns on, then off, then on, and repeats):**

Frequency:

[image]

Period:

[image]

High/Low time:

[image]

Duty Cycle:

[image]

Here are the schematics for both (Monostable on the left, Astable on the right):

[image]